# Expose APIs from Sitecore CD

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I want to create Web API application running on CD environment for Sitecore, to expose some content from Sitecore to other applications on other servers, is that possible ? is there any limitation from Sitecore to do that?

Answer (score 1):

For Web API runnning on CD are few constrainsts. Next settings you need to apply on CDs.

```
<site name="yourSiteName">
  <patch:attribute name="itemwebapi.mode">AdvancedSecurity</patch:attribute>
  <patch:attribute name="itemwebapi.access">ReadOnly</patch:attribute>
  <patch:attribute name="itemwebapi.allowanonymousaccess">false</patch:attribute>
</site>
```

More informartions about WebApi you can find [here](https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/modules/sitecore%20item%20web%20api/sitecore_item_web_api_developer_guide_sc66-71-usletter.pdf)

Comment: Use the IIS URL Rewrite module to protect access to these APIs to certain Client IPs only.  Even with security and "read-only" access these are dangerous methods to expose to the public internet as many Sitecore items contain settings that may expose information you'd rather was not made public

Comment: @RichardHauer what if i create my own APIs, and no need to use Item Web APis and i can expose what i want, i think this is  better  right ?

Comment: The ItemWebAPI is OK for circumstances where generic access to Sitecore data is required.  The most common use-case is facilitating integrations with other systems.  If your case is just exposing some data via a REST interface then custom Web API controllers are perfecto.  These can be safely exposed to the public because the data they expose is public anyway, but they should not allow arbitrary retrieval of Sitecore items by Id/Path/etc